# SQL to remove Zero's in the string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

SQL to remove Zero's in the string for a particular column.  I am tried using the REPLACE but it is completing removing all the 0's

EXAMPLE: "(REPLACE(Column,'0','')" But that didn't solved my problem.  It removed all the Zero's which is not the requirement.

Can some one help me in writing the SQL statement to remove only 1st zero from the string.

Column

00-01-09

07-00-02

03-04-00

03-04-06

---

Result

0-1-9

7-0-2

3-4-0

3-4-6

Thank you

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server(IE Microsoft)?

Comment: Thank you for the response John.  It is Mysql

Comment: @Abhi - what is the column type?

Comment: If it is MySQL, don't include the SQL Server tag. They are not the same thing; SQL Server refers to the Microsoft SQL Server DBMS and is quite specific to that product. Please use only the tags that actually are applicable to your question, and read the description of the tag before adding it to make sure it means what you think it does. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Sure Thanks.  I won't do that from next time.

Comment: @Abhi - Can you filter out your 0's on the front end?  Or does it have to be in the select statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select substring(REPLACE(concat('-', Column), '-0', '-'), 2)
```

This time, there is a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/37657) showing it working.

Comment: Result: `00-01-09` -> `019`

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  But that is not what I am looking for

Comment: @Abhi . . . Half a thought isn't quite a solution.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select concat(trim(leading 0 from substr(col1,2,2)) , 
              trim(leading 0 from substr(col1,5,2)) , 
              substr(col1,8,1))
from t;
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/388456/5) I was working with

**Results:**

```
1-1-1 
3-4-0
```

Comment: Thank you
but it is returning wrong for 00-07-09 to -7-9 instead of 0-7-9

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very elegant, but should work if it's just a "one time" thing:

Step 1:

Create a temporary table with six fields. 3 for original numbers and 3 for cleaned numbers.

Step 2: parse out and insert your original values into temp table first 3 fields:

insert into temp_table(first_number,second_number,third_number)
select
left(field,2) as first_number,
substring(field,3,2) as second_number,
substring(field(6,2) as third_number
from original_table

Step 2: "clean" each number with the following statement:

update temp_table 
set first_number_cleaned=substring(first_number,2,1)
where left(first_number,1)=0;

update temp_table
set first_number_cleaned=first_number
where left(first_number,1)<>0

repeat for each number

Step 4: update original table or create new one however you need to join it:

select
concat(first_number_cleaned,'-',second_number_cleaned,'-',third_number_cleaned) as cleaned_string
from temp_table

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr(c,2,2) || substr(c,5,2) || substr(c,8,1) 
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for time.  It is not working returning "1"

Comment: You need to have PIPES_AS_CONCAT in your @@sql_mode if you want to use the standard || operator. If you for some reason dont want that you can use the concat function `select concat(concat(substr(c,2,2),substr(c,5,2)),substr(c,8,1)) 
from t;`